# Hot to change export data in vue 3 &

Tags: vue.js, recaptcha, inertiajs

Here is my code

```
export default {
    name: 'form-loading-spinner',
    data(){  
        return{
            loading: false,
            form : {
                phone: "",
                token: null,
            },
        }
    },
    methods:{
            recaptcha(){
                this.loading = true;                
                let form = this.form;               
                    grecaptcha.ready(function() {                                  
                        grecaptcha.execute('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {                                     
                            form.token =  token;
                            Inertia.post("/phone/send", form, {
                                preserveScroll: true, onSuccess: () => this.loading = false
                            })
                            });                        
                        }) 
                        // this.loading = false; not working                     
            },
            reset(){
                this.loading =  false;
            },

    }
}
```

This is starting the spinner on button

`this.loading = true;`

This is button logic

```
  <button type="submit" :disabled="form.processing">
  <span >send</span>                                    
  <svg v-if="loading" .../></svg>
  </button>
```

I am trying to stop spinner by this code

> onSuccess: () => this.loading = false

But I got this error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'loading')

I think that I can`t get the data.loading from grecaptcha function, but maybe there is some way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading: https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc

In your case you can create a temporary variable `self` and use it instead of `this` when `this` means something else in the context it is used.

```js
recaptcha() {
    const self = this;
    this.loading = true;                
    let form = this.form;               
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {                                  
        grecaptcha.execute('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {                                     
            form.token =  token;
            Inertia.post("/phone/send", form, {
                preserveScroll: true, onSuccess: () => self.loading = false
            })
        });                        
    }) 
    // this.loading = false; not working                     
},
```